# How can I upload questions of maths or physics in flutter app without using .pdf or any type form

Tags: android, flutter, performance, pdf, flutter-dependencies

In a Flutter android application, we implement a holiday homework project where teachers can upload assessments by pdf and students can download and upload their answers by pdf. Due to many students with respective classes and subjects, a bulk number of pdf were uploaded to the server, but our server does not have enough space for this. Google Forms and or any type of form cannot be implemented into this app because students can not write maths, physics, or chemistry problems using the normal mobile keyboard.

Is there any other way to arrange the assessment or holiday homework into this Android application and save space on the server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Flutter Math](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_math_fork) it helps to render math equations. With this you can save equations as text in your database and render it with that package, it will take less space but your teachers and students have to learn how to use it to rendering their equations, you can put a section in the app to explain that.

You can check the [demo](https://znjameswu.github.io/flutter_math_demo/#/) to view what is possible to do.